# rxjs - stop observable with a subject subscription

Tags: rxjs, observable, subject, unsubscribe

I created an Observable generating potentially infinite amount of data (e.g. a timer). This data is accessed through a subject, so multiple observers would receive the same values.

How to stop the Observable generating new values? (without modifying the implementation of the Observable)

```
// custom Observable, to visualize internal behavior
const timer$ = new rxjs.Observable(subscriber => {
  console.log("observable init");

  var counter = 0;
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    ++counter;
    console.log("observable %s",counter);
    subscriber.next(counter);
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    console.log("observable teardown");
    clearTimeout(intervalId);
  }
});

// subscribe through a subject
const subject$ = new rxjs.Subject();
timer$.subscribe(subject$);

const subscription = subject$.subscribe(value => console.log("observer %s", value));

// cancel subscription
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("unsubscribe observer");
  subscription.unsubscribe();
  // TODO how to stop Observable generating new values?
}, 3000);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gy4tfd5w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a dedicated and elegant way to solve this in RxJS.

Your requirement is to have

> multiple observers [...] receive the same values

That's called a *multicast* observable and there are certain *operators* that are used to create one from an ordinary "cold" observable.

For example, instead of creating an instance of `Subject` directly, you can just pipe the source observable to the `share` operator and it will create the `Subject` for you. The documentation of `share` reads:

> Returns a new Observable that multicasts (shares) the original Observable. As long as there is at least one Subscriber this Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. When all subscribers have unsubscribed it will unsubscribe from the source Observable.

The last sentence shows the subtle difference between `share` and `source$.subscribe(subject)`. With `share` a so-called `refCount` is kept that unsubscribes the `Subject` from its source automatically when there are no subscribers to it left.

Applied to your code, it looks like this:

```
const timer$ = 
    new rxjs.Observable(subscriber => {// your unchanged implementation})
    .pipe(
        share()
    );

const subscription = timer$.subscribe(value => console.log("observer %s", value));
```

Here is the full version with your example code:

https://jsfiddle.net/50q746ad/

By the way, `share` is not the only operator that performs multicasting. [There are great learning resources](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/) that go much more in depth on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to stop a crazy observable mid-flow.

By using a signal `Subject` and the rxjs operator: `takeUntil`

**Example**

```js
const stopSignal$ = new Subject();

infinitelyGenerating$
  .pipe(takeUntil(stopSignal$))
  .subscribe(val => {
    if (val === 'bad') {
      stopSignal$.next()
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -2):

So after some PUNISHING research I've added my own npm library for this problem.

`Improves previous answer by NOT having to add any extra convolution variables and ease of use.`

- [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dswrjc)
- [Repo](https://github.com/dontboyle/rxjs-serial-subscription/wiki)
- [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-serializable-subscription)

[image]